# How to avoid a quirk in formatted R output?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just tried to correct the R `data.frame` output formatting in a question.  The markdown looked right: 4 spaces in for each line and a code block appeared.  It all looked correct in the preview.  However on the final site, both when it was at stats.stackexchange and now it's in overflow, the code lines are visually out of joint.

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870620/aggregating-restructuring-hourly-time-series-data-in-r).  Press 'edit' to see what it looks like in preview.

Is this just me, or is there a problem with the markdown plugin, or perhaps an awkward interaction with R's dollars and dots?  Is there a work-around?  It's the second time I've seen this in a few days.

Comment: Same for me, on several other occasions! It looks like there's a conflict with `$` (parsed as $\LaTeX$ or whatever).

Comment: that is somehow avoided on the preview page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to mathjax parsing - $ is a special delimiter.  It appears to be fixed in the second revision of this post.

Comment: Thank you, Geoff.  (And thanks to the SE team.)

Comment: As you say, it is now fixed.  This implies is was *not* [status-bydesign](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)